# Where to put jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my row clickable on

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{% url "perception:detail" %}" data-turbolinks="false">
                        <td><a href="{{ object.loan.get_absolute_url }}" data-turbolinks="false">{{ object.loan }}</a></td>
                        <td><b>{{ object.current_balance }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ object.operation_error }}</td>
                        <td>{{ object.start_date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ object.end_date|default:"" }}</td>
                        <td>{{ object.created }}</td>
                        <td>{{ object.modified }}</td>
                    </tr>
```

in using the example

```
<tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://'>
        <td>Blah Blah</td> <td>1234567</td> <td>£158,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

So far I don't have any success in clicking on rows. The problem is located that I don't know where to insert

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
```

Could you tell me where do I put those five last lines?

Comment: you create new file js and put in index.html . dont write jquery in page html

Comment: how could I put in the index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should write in another file . I name it is script.js . And put it in html

```
<script>script.js</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put script in HTML inside script tags

```
<script></script>
```

Make sure you have jQuery referenced as well so it will work, generally it's standard practice to put your script in a separate file and reference it in the HTML page like the example below with jQuery, but for just base functionality putting it in script tags will work.

```
<head>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put that in an external JS document and link to the document in the footer, right before the closing body tag. Alternately, you can just paste the code as is right before the closing body tag. Make sure you are importing JQuery before this script as that is a JQuery function."

If you put it in your index doc, you need to wrap it with:

```
 <script></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="path_to_jquery"></script>
  <script>

    $(".clickable-row").on('click',function() {
        //window.location = $(this).data("href");
        alert('clicked');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://'>
        <td>Blah Blah</td> <td>1234567</td> <td>£158,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Unless you are having any other JS error prior to executing this it should work as expected, check your console for other errors.\

Also there is good info over here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script isn't functionning the way you intendend is because you use `window.location` wrong :

Therefore use `document.location.href = $(this).data("href");` that is also known as redirection in same tab.